# Determine number of factors in EFA (R) using Comparison Data

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

I am looking for ways to determine number of optimal factors in R `factanal` function. The most used method (conduct a pca and use scree plot to determine the number of factors) is already known to me. I have found a method described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32669/vss-criterion-for-the-number-of-factors-in-rs-psych-package) to be easier for non technical folks like me. Unfortunately the R script is no longer accessible in which the method was implemented. I was wondering if there is a package available in R that does the same?
The method was originally proposed in this study: [Determining the number of factors to retain in an exploratory factor analysis using comparison data of known factorial structure](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21966933).

Comment: search for parallel analysis. I think the psych package had this. I think they had Horn's analysis, but it would be better to use Glorfeld's adaptation: might be wortt searching to see if someone has released some code.

Comment: quick search led to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/paran/index.html . Although a quick approx to glorfelds is not too difficult to code up.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the code and gonna try `paran` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The R code is now moved [here](http://ruscio.pages.tcnj.edu/quantitative-methods-program-code/) as per the author.

Answer (score 0):

EFA.dimensions ist also a nice and easy to use package for that

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30263907)